# Get ids of elements within a div and then combine them into an integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

If I have a `<div>` that has variable elements in it, each with a different `id`, which is one number — so for instance, three images with the `id`s `1`, `2` and `3` — how do I write a function to get those `id`s and then export them all together as an integer instead of a string?

At the moment I have a function that grabs the ids and exports them, but there's a problem. Say I put three images with `id`s `1`, `2` and `3` into the `<div>`. When it exports the `id`s and goes to the database, I don't get 123's entry; I get 1, 2, or 3. I imagine it's because the function is exporting it as `1,2,3` instead of `123`. Can anyone help?

My code (where `#div` is the parent `<div>` and `children` are the elements with the `id`s I want to gather):

```js
$("#submit").click(function () {
    $("#div").children().each(function(n, i) {
        var boxid = this.id;
        // Do something with the ids
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the result as 123 integer, you can use `map` method and then `join` the result.

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var boxid = $("#div").children().map(function() {
          return this.id;
    }).get().join('') 

    boxid = Number(boxid)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rEfXb/

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you to everyone, accepted this one just cause of the simplicity of it.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be using a digit as an id but if you are,

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
     var sum = 0;
     $("#div").children().each(function(n, i) {
      var boxid = this.id;
      sum += boxid;
    });
});
```

Comment: this will return `6` instead of `123`

Comment: Yes, if I remember right, ids starting with numbers are invalid according to the standards.

Comment: @VijayDev in HTML5 it can be any character

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
var idString = $("#div").children().map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get().join("");
```

If you need it to be an actual int, use parseInt.  Otherwise, you can just use the string.

```
var idInt = parseInt(idString,10);
```

But note that numeric `id`s are not valid prior to html 5.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` for that :)

Let's assume we have this html:

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="1"></div>
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3"></div>
  <div id="4"></div>
</div>​
```

Then you can use this code:

```
jQuery('#outer > *').toArray().reduce(function(value, elem) {
  return value + elem.id
}, '')​​​​
// => '1234'
```